# cronjob issue not running

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i created RC-Cron.txt in /etc/cron.d folder
i have these lines in there:

```
MAILTO=mymailaddress

#rainbowcode
5 8 * * * root /home/rainbowcode/DB-Query-Script.php rainbowcode yesterday mymailaddress
```

my cronjob is not running, i see from other examples the script it must run is a .sh??? and can i save the cronjob as .txt??

can someone help me fix this please?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

That hashmark in the beginning makes that line a comment. I'm also guesing `root` is the user you want to run it as, remove that from the crontab, and add the command to root's crontab.